# Delphi Trying to show a percentage completed chart based on query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to generate a bar chart (using TChart in Delphi 2010) to show the percentage completed of filming projects in progress.  I am hoping that i can use a query to get the final percentage completed for each film.  From the start,we know the number of shots a film requires. This is stored in table FILM. In table SHOTS, we record the FILMID and how many shots have been taken to date. The table structures can be seen here:

[image]

1) I realise I need to count up the number of shots taken so far, so i've used this SQL statement:

```
SELECT CountOfShots.CountOfShotNumber, FILM.NumberOfShots, [CountOfShotNumber]/[NumberOfShots]*100 AS Complete
FROM CountOfShots INNER JOIN FILM ON CountOfShots.FilmID = FILM.FilmID;
```

..and this query, called 'CountOfShots' gives me the following:

[image]

2) Now, to work out percentage completion, my second SQL statement (using the last query) is as follows:

```
SELECT CountOfShots.CountOfShotNumber, FILM.NumberOfShots, [CountOfShotNumber]/[NumberOfShots]*100 AS Complete
FROM CountOfShots INNER JOIN FILM ON CountOfShots.FilmID = FILM.FilmID;
```

This gives me what I'm looking for as you can see below:

[image]

Now, rather than having two queries, is there a way i could combine the two queries, perhaps having a sub-query. I've been trying to figure this one out, but has stumped me.

3) If I had this query pulling the data I should then hopefully be able to use a chart in Delphi (TChart) to show percentage completions.

Sorry this is long winded.  Other details are:
(Using ADO connection, with a MS Access 2003 Database).

thanks

Comment: The two queries seem to be the same.  I think you intended the first one to be the query for CountOfShots.

Comment: To me this seems more like SQL related question. So you should probably add SQL tag to the question and remove Delphi tag since the question is all about queries and not showing the resulting data in Delphi. This way you improve the chances of getting desired answer more quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a left outer join instead of an inner join. That way if you have films without shot records it will show the film as 0%.

```
SELECT film.filmid, film.numberofshots, count(shot.filmid) AS countofshotnumber,
       count(shot.filmid)/film.numberofshots AS percentoffilmshot
  FROM film left outer join shot on film.filmid = shot.filmid
GROUP BY film.filmid, film.numberofshots
```